# DEP6200: Bootstrapping failed. Device cannot be found. - How do I stop it looking for a phone?

Tags: uwp-xaml

I found an example that uses Windows.Storage at [the windows universal samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/FolderEnumeration)

However when I run the example I get an error

```
DEP6200: Bootstrapping failed. Device cannot be found. SmartDeviceException
- Deployment failed because no device was detected. 
Make sure a device is connected and powered on.  
[0x80131500]    FolderEnumeration
```

I don't want to use the phone. I just want to get the sample working in Windows 10.

[image: references]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the configuration set to ARM.
When I changed it to x64 it worked
[image: configuration]